# Find all direct subordinates of a particular employee in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table of employees and their bosses:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Personnel (

emp CHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,

boss CHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL REFERENCES Personnel(emp),

salary DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 100.00);
```

[image]
I need to find all direct subordinates of a particular employee. My code shows only one employee for each boss:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT E2.emp FROM Personnel E2 WHERE E1.emp = E2.boss), E1.emp FROM Personnel E1;
```

**Problem:** is to print all the employees of each boss **in one row**!
Here is the code to construct the database:

```sql
INSERT INTO Personnel VALUES('Ivanov', Null, 1000);

INSERT INTO Personnel VALUES('Petrov', 'Ivanov', 900);

INSERT INTO Personnel VALUES('Sidorov', 'Ivanov', 850);

INSERT INTO Personnel VALUES('Smirnov', 'Petrov', 840);

INSERT INTO Personnel VALUES('Fedorov', 'Petrov', 800);

INSERT INTO Personnel VALUES('Andreev', 'Sidorov', 700);

INSERT INTO Personnel VALUES('Alekseev', 'Sidorov', 700);

INSERT INTO Personnel VALUES('Borisov', 'Sidorov', 740);
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data as *text tables* is much preferred over images.  And a db/sql fiddle is helpful.  Also define what "direct subordinate" means.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've added the INSERTS to generate the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Direct subordinate" means that the boss is the person in question.  Hence a simple `where` clause should suffice:

```
select p.*
from personnel p
where p.boss = ?;
```

The `?` is a placeholder for the boss's name.

Comment: @student . . . Your comment is totally unhelpful.  What do you mean "doesn't work"?  It should do exactly what is intended and that should answer your question.

Comment: The output is empty.

Comment: OK, how do I iterate over all the bosses(employees)?

Comment: @student . . . That is not the question you asked here.